# Turning off warnings in Octave

Tags: matlab, warnings, octave, batch-processing

I am running a Matlab compatible script in Octave, so I was awaiting few warnings concerning the '&' and '|' commands and others, so I added the "warning('all','off')" in my now Octave script, but it doesn't seem to do anything... I don't get it, I still get the same warnings!

Any ideas how to solve this please?

PS: I am running the Octave script in batch mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be `warning('off','all')` or just `warning('off')`, your arguments are inverted.

Docs: https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/warning.html

> **warning ("off", id)**
>
> If **the first argument is "on" or "off"**, set the state of a particular warning using the identifier id. If the first argument is "query", query the state of this warning instead. **If the identifier is omitted, a value of "all" is assumed.**

---

*Obligatory note that it's probably a better idea to address the warnings than turn them off, and that you should at least re-enable the warnings after specific functions where you want to ignore them*.

Comment: The command is correct, I just inverted the order in the question. Thank you for the remark! I will definitely adress each warning alone, and disable it when necessary.

Comment: @Wallflower btw, since all arguments are strings in this case, you can also call this using [command syntax](https://docs.octave.org/v7.1.0/Command-Syntax-and-Function-Syntax.html) if you prefer (i.e. `warning off all` instead of `warning( "off", "all")` )